# Change post template the proper way

Tags: customization, custom-field, metabox, post-formats, plugins

I'm trying to create an option on edit posts screen (backend) to select different post template based the selection and I need your opinions guys if that is the proper way.

Here is what I've tried so far and is working:

First I create meta box using [CMB2 Custom Fields](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2)

```
add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'select_template' );

function select_template() {

// Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
$prefix = '_templatever_';


 /* Initiate the metabox */
$tempver = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'            => 'template_options',
    'title'         => __( 'Template Options', 'idver' ),
    'object_types'  => array( 'post', ), // Post type
    'context'       => 'side',
    'priority'      => 'high',
    'show_names'    => true, // Show field names on the left
) );

$tempver->add_field( array(
    'name'             => 'Select Version',
    'id'               => 'temp_ver',
    'type'             => 'select',
    'show_option_none' => true,
    'options'          => array(
        'v1' => __( 'Version 1', 'cmb' ),

    ),
) );
```

}

Then in single.php:

```
$version = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'temp_ver', true );
                            if ($version == 'v1') {
                                get_template_part('single-video'); 
                            } else {

                            }
```

Now when I choose **Version 1** the template change to **single-video**.

So is that the proper way to do this or is better to use post formats?

Also is better (speed) to implement the plugin code n the theme code or just install the plugin?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's generally better to include the CMB2 plugin. As far as your question, there are a lot of ways to go about this, but I think your way is a solid one. I would make a couple changes. I'd update your option values to be the name of your template-parts:

```
'options' => array(
    'single-video' => 'Single Video',
),
```

Then I would add a helper function to your theme's functions.php:

```
function idver_get_post_template_part( $post_id ) {
    $template = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'temp_ver', 1 );
    if ( ! $template ) {
        $template = 'default'; // Whatever your fallback template part is
    }

    get_template_part( $template ); 
}
```

(obviously, update 'default' to whatever your default/fallback template part should be. If NO default, that helper function should be updated a bit)

Then in your single.php, just call:

```
idver_get_post_template_part( get_the_ID() );
```